# Display many User's calendar in sharepoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, calendar, outlook

i created a calendar list and I want to display an events form outlook of few users in this list.

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details of what you are trying to achieve.  Do you mean that you want to user's Outlook calendar to be displayed on the SharePoint calendar?